# French Tarot suits probability

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, card-games

[French Tarot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Tarot) is played with a 78-card deck.
The deck includes four suits (hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs).
Each suit contains 14 cards: 1, 2, ..., 10, Jack, Knight, Queen, King.
There are also 21 numbered trump cards and one unnumbered Fool trump card.
Four players are dealt 18-card hands and the dog is dealt 6 cards.

Knowing that I have 5 hearts in my hand what is the probability that the other player with the most hearts has 4 hearts?

I tried:

$\dfrac{
\binom{9}{4}\cdot\binom{69}{14}}{\binom{78}{18}
}=0.0916$

but I know the correct result is 0.48 (from a Tarot book which includes probability tables).
I think I'm failing to have the proper conditional probability for the 3 other players and the dog. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the dog considered a player? In any case, you have to consider how to distribute the remaining nine hearts are distributed to the remaining three players and the dog so that no other player (including the dog) receives more than four hearts.

Comment: The dog is not considered a player. After bidding it is given to the taker/declarer who then must put aside an equal number of cards. It allows him to remove a suit from his game to be able to use trumps when that suit is used for example.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the dog receiving 6 hearts is satisfactory, since the dog is not a player.  So, you have 7 cases to consider, based on the dog receiving $~k~$ cards, where $~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,6\}.~$  Then, you have to consider the mutually exclusive ways of distributing $~(9-k)~$ hearts among the 3 players.  For example, if $~k = 0,~$ you would have to consider the distributions (0,4,4,1), (0,4,3,2), (0,3,3,3), where the 1st number refers to what the dog receives and the other three numbers refer to the other 3 players, *in some order*.

Comment: Re previous comment, if I understand correctly, you are (in effect) dealing with a 73 card deck, since all that is known is that you were dealt 5 hearts.  So, you have 64 non-hearts, and 9 hearts remaining in the deck.

Comment: Can you add an image of the relevant probability table from your Tarot book?  Or a table with the values from a few rows.  My answer below gives $0.472$ as the correct probability, which is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're dealt your hand, which is stipulated to have $5$ hearts and $13$ non-hearts, the remaining $60$-card deck consists of $9$ hearts and $51$ non-hearts.  Now, let $P_{a,b,c}$ be the probability that players $A$, $B$, and $C$ are dealt exactly $a$, $b$, and $c$ hearts from that remaining deck, respectively, where $3 \le a+b+c\le 9$:
$$
P_{a,b,c}=\frac{\frac{9!}{a! b! c!(9-a-b-c)!}\cdot\frac{51!}{ (18-a)! (18-b)! (18-c)! (a+b+c-3)!}}{\frac{60!}{18! 18! 18! 6!}}.
$$
Here we've counted the ways to choose which hearts each player receives (subject to the $abc$-constraint), times the ways to choose which non-hearts each player receives (ditto), divided by the ways to choose the $18$-card hands independent of the $abc$-constraint.

You want the probability that one of $\{A,B,C\}$ has $4$ hearts, and none of them has more than $4$.  That leaves these possibilities for $(a,b,c)$, up to permutations: $(4,0,0)$, $(4,1,0)$, $(4,1,1)$, $(4,2,0)$, $(4,2,1)$, $(4,2,2)$, $(4,3,0)$, $(4,3,1)$, $(4,3,2)$, $(4,4,0)$, $(4,4,1)$.  The result is
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
p_4 &=& 3P_{4,0,0}+6P_{4,1,0} + 3P_{4,1,1}+6P_{4,2,0}+6P_{4,2,1} \\ &&+3P_{4,2,2}+6P_{4,3,0}+6P_{4,3,1}+6P_{4,3,2}+3P_{4,4,0}+3P_{4,4,1}
\\
&\approx& 0.4720001,
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where the coefficients account for the number of distinct permutations of $(a,b,c)$.  Similarly, to cover the remaining options: the probability that the player besides you with the most hearts has *fewer* than $4$ hearts is $p_{<4}\approx 0.2841916$, and the probability that he has *more* than $4$ hearts is $p_{>4}\approx 0.2438084$.  The three options add up to $1$, as they must.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer this is really helpful for me. I prefer not to include a picture of the book to avoid any copyright issue. I'm going to double-check this with other cells of the table in the book to confirm. Also I will try to figure out why the book says 48.0 for this specific case.